# Naming convention using java

Tags: java, eclipse, loops, soap, while-loop

So I have been building a soap message which takes elements and builds a soap structure. Don't be scared to take a stab at this if your unsure of this content. I'm looking for a changing variable name of some sort. All of the contents bellow are part of a line. Their can be several lines within a xml file so I have decided to loop it in an array, and insert them as an element individually. In the second chunk of code you can see "CHANGINGVARIABLE" however I do not know how to avoid this and keep inserting elements based on how many their are without predefining variables. Any tips or help would be greatly appreciated to make this work!

```
boolean finished = false; // true if there is no more item to process 

while(!finished) {
    String itemNumberz = eElement.getElementsByTagName("ItemNumber").item(cnt).getTextContent();
    String receiptTypez = eElement.getElementsByTagName("ReceiptType").item(cnt).getTextContent();
    String descriptionz = eElement.getElementsByTagName("ReceiptType").item(cnt).getTextContent();
    String locationCodez = eElement.getElementsByTagName("ReceiptType").item(cnt).getTextContent();
    String quantityz = eElement.getElementsByTagName("ReceiptType").item(cnt).getTextContent();
    String UnitOfMeasurez = eElement.getElementsByTagName("ReceiptType").item(cnt).getTextContent();
    String UnitCostz = eElement.getElementsByTagName("ReceiptType").item(cnt).getTextContent();

    listItemNumbers.add(itemNumberz);
    listReceiptTypes.add(receiptTypez);
    listDescriptions.add(descriptionz);
    listLocationCodes.add(locationCodez);
    listQuantitys.add(quantityz);
    listUnitOfMeasures.add(UnitOfMeasurez);
    listUnitCosts.add(UnitCostz);

    ++cnt;

    finished = (cnt >= eElement.getElementsByTagName("ItemNumber").getLength());
    //finished = (cnt >= eElement.getElementsByTagName("ReceiptType").getLength());
    System.out.println(cnt);
}

// use them :
int indexYouNeed = 1;
String itemNumber44 = listItemNumbers.get(indexYouNeed);
//System.out.println(itemNumber44);
```

Below is how I am applying them into the soap message.

```
while(cnt < 0) {
    String name = (cnt + "add");
    int[] CHANGINGVARIABLE = new int[cnt];
    CHANGINGVARIABLE[x] = someValue;


    SOAPElement CHANGINGVARIABLE = soapBodyElem7.addChildElement("LineItem");

    SOAPElement soapBodyElem9 = CHANGINGVARIABLE.addChildElement("ItemNumber");
    soapBodyElem9.addTextNode(listItemNumbers.get(cnt - 1));
    SOAPElement soapBodyElemaa = CHANGINGVARIABLE.addChildElement("ReceiptType");
    soapBodyElemaa.addTextNode(listReceiptTypes.get(cnt - 1));
    SOAPElement soapBodyElemaaa = CHANGINGVARIABLE.addChildElement("Description");
    soapBodyElemaaa.addTextNode(listDescriptions.get(cnt - 1));
    SOAPElement soapBodyElemaaaa = CHANGINGVARIABLE.addChildElement("Quantity");
    soapBodyElemaaaa.addTextNode(listQuantitys.get(cnt - 1));
    SOAPElement soapBodyElemaaaaa = CHANGINGVARIABLE.addChildElement("UnitOfMeasurement");
    soapBodyElemaaaaa.addTextNode(listUnitOfMeasures.get(cnt - 1));
    SOAPElement soapBodyElemaaaaaa = CHANGINGVARIABLE.addChildElement("UnitPrice");
    soapBodyElemaaaaaa.addTextNode(listUnitCosts.get(cnt - 1));
    SOAPElement soapBodyElemaaaaaaa = CHANGINGVARIABLE.addChildElement("LocationCode");
    soapBodyElemaaaaaaa.addTextNode(listLocationCodes.get(cnt - 1));
```

Comment: Please tell me if I understood your problem correctly. You have "repeating" lines of code in the second block like: changingVar = soapBodyElem7... changingVar2 = soapBodyElem8... changingVar3 = soapBodyElem9..?

Comment: @MichaelSanchez In order to define a SOAP Element, you have to create a variable. Where I have changing variable, I need different variables for that area. So defined different variables. Now I would easily use predefined variable names, however their may be 10000 lines or 2.

Comment: Not sure if you've solved this already. The code sample is confusing though where CHANGINGVARIABLE is declared as int[] then later as SOAPElement. Have you tried using a SOAPElement array or list?

Comment: @MichaelSanchez Sanchez That I am unsure of how to do. However if this makes a little more sense. The first set of code pulls the content from an xml file. Now the content needs to be stored as an element to make a soap message. However, where Changingvariable is, you can simply define that as v1, v2, v3, however, that is only if their is one line. What if their is 20 lines? the cnt will keep track of that, but how can i make a loop to get this to work for several?

Answer (score 0):

Given your explanation, you can either choose between using a list or an array. Then add new SOAPElements to the list or array by looping.

```
**For Array:**
SOAPElement[] soapArr = new SOAPElement[size];
for(int i=0; i < size; i++) {
    soapArr[i] = new SOAPElement();
}

**For List:**
List soapList = new LinkedList();
for(int i=0; i < size; i++){
    soapList.add(new SOAPElement());
}
```

Then loop through that second code chunk while referring to the CHANGINGVARIABLEs as the following:

`soapArr[i]` or `soapList.get(i)`.

I hope I'm understanding your need properly.